# Importing React Typescript component with undeclared alias

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I have been learning React through [JHipster](https://jhipster.tech), a boilerplate generator for Angular/React and Spring-Boot.

The webapp is generated with Typescript instead of Javascript, so the entry point is as follows.

The app.tsx imports a react component named **AppRoutes** listed below.

What I could not understand from the code is: the routes.tsx component (or element?) exports a **Routes** variable. And the file is named **routes.tsx**.

How is it possible that the code is importing **AppRoutes** and it works?

- app.tsx:

```
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import './app.scss';

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Card } from 'reactstrap';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ToastContainer, ToastPosition, toast } from 'react-toastify';

import { IRootState } from 'app/shared/reducers';
import { getSession } from 'app/shared/reducers/authentication';
import { getProfile } from 'app/shared/reducers/application-profile';
import Header from 'app/shared/layout/header/header';
import Footer from 'app/shared/layout/footer/footer';
import { hasAnyAuthority } from 'app/shared/auth/private-route';
import ErrorBoundary from 'app/shared/error/error-boundary';
import { AUTHORITIES } from 'app/config/constants';
import AppRoutes from 'app/routes';

export interface IAppProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps {}

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProps> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSession();
    this.props.getProfile();
  }

  render() {
    const paddingTop = '60px';
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="app-container" style={{ paddingTop }}>
          <ToastContainer
            position={toast.POSITION.TOP_LEFT as ToastPosition}
            className="toastify-container"
            toastClassName="toastify-toast"
          />
          <ErrorBoundary>
            <Header
              isAuthenticated={this.props.isAuthenticated}
              isAdmin={this.props.isAdmin}
              ribbonEnv={this.props.ribbonEnv}
              isInProduction={this.props.isInProduction}
              isSwaggerEnabled={this.props.isSwaggerEnabled}
              accountName={this.props.accountName}
            />
          </ErrorBoundary>
          <div className="container-fluid view-container" id="app-view-container">
            <Card className="jh-card">
              <ErrorBoundary>
                <AppRoutes />
              </ErrorBoundary>
            </Card>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ authentication, applicationProfile }: IRootState) => ({
  isAuthenticated: authentication.isAuthenticated,
  isAdmin: hasAnyAuthority(authentication.account.authorities, [AUTHORITIES.ADMIN]),
  ribbonEnv: applicationProfile.ribbonEnv,
  isInProduction: applicationProfile.inProduction,
  isSwaggerEnabled: applicationProfile.isSwaggerEnabled,
  accountName: authentication.account.firstName
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getSession, getProfile };

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

- routes.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

import Login from 'app/modules/login/login';
import Register from 'app/modules/account/register/register';
import Activate from 'app/modules/account/activate/activate';
import PasswordResetInit from 'app/modules/account/password-reset/init/password-reset-init';
import PasswordResetFinish from 'app/modules/account/password-reset/finish/password-reset-finish';
import Logout from 'app/modules/login/logout';
import Home from 'app/modules/home/home';
import Entities from 'app/entities';
import PrivateRoute from 'app/shared/auth/private-route';
import ErrorBoundaryRoute from 'app/shared/error/error-boundary-route';
import { AUTHORITIES } from 'app/config/constants';

// tslint:disable:space-in-parens
const Account = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "account" */ 'app/modules/account'),
  loading: () => <div>loading ...</div>
});

const Admin = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "administration" */ 'app/modules/administration'),
  loading: () => <div>loading ...</div>
});
// tslint:enable

const Routes = () => (
  <div className="view-routes">
    <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Switch>
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/logout" component={Logout} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/register" component={Register} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/activate/:key?" component={Activate} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/reset/request" component={PasswordResetInit} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/reset/finish/:key?" component={PasswordResetFinish} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.ADMIN]} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/account" component={Account} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.ADMIN, AUTHORITIES.USER]} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/entity" component={Entities} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.USER]} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

export default Routes;
```

Comment: It's default exporting Routes, which means that when importing it you can alias it to whatever you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Thanks for the link. After many years of doing just backend development, the world of ES6 and React is quite huge. If you put your comment as an answer I'll gladly mark it as the answer to this post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because in `Routes.tsx` it is default exporting the component, which means that when importing it in `App.tsx` you could alias it to whatever you want when importing, it'll know to resolve it to that component.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for more details about exporting/importing in ES6.